# Real physical path of file in mvc web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am building a sample application using MVC web api. I am getting the file name from the POST request. If I am using the code below to get the physical path of the file, it is returning the path of the application folder instead of the file path in my other drive (say D: drive)

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/~" + fileName);
```

Comment: sorry for that but that was typo from my side, i am using "~/" this only ;)

Comment: I am sure about the file name is not empty, and about the virtual directory in IIS ? can you help me out about this i have no idea about the sec question ?

Comment: Ignore virtual directory,my poor English~ Can you show your `fileName`,and the `result` here?

Comment: "D:\Harender\DotNetPractice\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\student.xls" here student.xls is the file name and rest of the path of my application folder. The real path of my file is D:\student.xls.

Comment: Your file does not belong to your application! You can use `"D:\"+fileName` directly,there is no need to use `MapPath`

Answer (score 2):

Please use below statement

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "/" + fileName
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to do this way:

```
1. Create a application setting:

      <appSettings >
        <add key="FolderPath" value="D:\"/>
      </appSettings>
2. Change your code:
    string root= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FolderPath"].ToString();
    var physicalFilePath =root + fileName;
```

Comment: yeh i thought this initially - but feel there must be a built in way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath` always gives you the absolute path from the root of the directory to the current directory you are working on.

If you want your files to be read from a specific directory:

- Decide a common path where your file will be available, say `D:\`.
- Put this path to web.config file under app settings with a name, say 'FileDirectory'.
- Combine the path of `FileDirectory` (after reading from appsettings) and your file, say `Path.Combine(FileDirectory, file)`

You will get the file.